# php script to convert xml to dtd

Tags: php, xml, dtd

Is there any PHP script to convert XML file to DTD.

I tried a lot. I can able to find tools but can't PHP script.

Is there any?

any help will be thankful...

Fero

Comment: Do you mean an XML Schema file or just an arbitrary XML file?

Comment: just arbitrary file Gordon... sorry for late...

Comment: I don't know any, but it would be cool, if possible. I mean, a DTD also specifies things like nesting rules and data types. Creating a DTD from an XML files is like constructing English grammar rules from this comment. Does the absence of the word 'biking' mean it is not a legal word?

Comment: A sample of the XML would be nice as well as if there are any common attributes that will be in all XML to be converted to DTD

Comment: your'e right Pepijin.. But there are some tools to convert the xml schema in to DTD. will you please explain how is that possible? sorry if i am wrong. I am a newbie to this section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating a DTD from an XML file is something I've not seen done quite often -- one of the main reasons being that **you cannot be sure the XML file you used to generate the DTD will contain everything that the DTD should define**.

i.e. the generated DTD will only contain the elements and attributes that were present in that specific XML file *-- which doesn't necessarily means all elements and attributes that should be accepted when using it later*.

That being said, I haven't found any PHP tool to create a DTD from an XML file...

... But I've found a JAVA one : **[DTDGenerator - A tool to generate XML DTDs](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/dtdgen.html)** *(quoting)* :

> DTDGenerator is a program that **takes
>   an XML document as input and produces
>   a Document Type Definition (DTD) as
>   output**.
>
> The aim of the program is to give you
>   a quick start in writing a DTD. 
> The
>   DTD is one of the many possible DTDs
>   to which the input document conforms.
>   
> Typically you will want to examine the
>   DTD and edit it to describe your
>   intended documents more precisely.

A couple of nice things about this `DTDGenerator` program are :

- There are some explanations on the website about the basic ideas of how this works
- The source code is provided
- It's only less that 600 lines long

  - which means one should be able to understand without too much efforts
  - and **possibly port it to PHP** ?
  - And there are some comments in the source code *-- which would help*.
- It's published under [MPL](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/MPL-1.0.html) *-- which means open source ; which is good, if you want to port it*

Starting from that program's source code, it should be possible to write some PHP code *(if you cannot execute JAVA, and really need this to be written in PHP)* to do the same thing : the basic ideas are not that hard :

- You have to go through the XML structure
- **building a tree-representation of it**, on each starting tag

  - which means elements
  - that can have attributes
- And, when you've finished going through the XML document, you have to build the DTD from your reprensentation of the document

  - That might be the hard part -- looking at the source of the JAVA tool I linked to, it reprensents quite a large number of lines of code ^^

Nice thing of taking a look at this **[`DTDGenerator`](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/dtdgen.html)** before starting is that its author already thought about this process -- and already **identified some situations that you might not think about** ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I found that might be of use: http://www.hitsw.com/xml_utilites/

There is also a class that appears to be promising: http://phpclasses.2by2host.com/browse/package/250.html